# Sample size for a desired accuracy

Tags: statistics

I recently revised for my statistics paper, and in a sample paper given by my lecturer, I am puzzled by how he derives with the answer.

So. here is the question
A study based on a sample size of 36 reported a mean of 87 with a margin of error of 10 for 95% confidence.

You desire a margin of error of 2.5 with the same confidence level. What is the sample size that will give you that kind of accuracy? Assume that we know the population variance.

Question: How do I answer this question without the population variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without explicitly saying so, the question asks us to assume either normality, or sufficiently nice distribution that the sample mean has a close enough to normal distribution.

The margin of error with sample size $n$ is $\frac{c\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, where in our case $c\approx 1.96$, though that will turn out to be unimportant.  Here $\sigma$ is the population variance, which we will not need to know.

We are told that $\frac{c\sigma}{\sqrt{36}}=10$. We want to choose $n$ so that $\frac{c\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}=2.5$. So the margin of error has to decrease by a factor of $4$. It follows that $\sqrt{n}$ must be $4\sqrt{36}$. That gives $n=576$.